# Restful Web Services - How to retrieve 10+ input params

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, restful-architecture

We can retrieve input params using different type of annotations like... @PathParam,@FormParam  ..etc.

and in code,

```
public Customer getDetails(@FormParam("custNo") int no) {
```

But what if i have 10+ values in the input form ? is there any other way ?  I have searched in Google but all the time i am seeing @PathParams and @FormParams.  Can we bind all input form values into some object and retrieve ?

Thank you
Siva

Comment: I'm puzzled by the tags you chose (`web services`, `rest`, `soap`, `restful-architecture`). Isn't your annotations coming from `jax-rs`? If yes, how could it be tagged with `soap`? For reference, which [implementation of jax-rs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services#Implementations) do you use?

Comment: All tags are related to web services only..! any way i am using jersey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, starting with Jersey 2.0 you can use the `@BeanParam` annotation to wrap a bunch of parameters in a Java bean. Example:

```
public class CustomerDetails {
    @FormParam("custNo")
    public int customerNumber;
    @FormParam("whatevs")
    public String whatever;

}

public Customer getDetails(@BeanParam CustomerDetails customer) {
   // ...
}
```

Documentation: https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.6/jersey/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html

Related question: [How do you map multiple query parameters to the fields of a bean on Jersey GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722506/how-do-you-map-multiple-query-parameters-to-the-fields-of-a-bean-on-jersey-get-r)

Comment: Perfect thanks man!
I saw different form param annotations but @BeanParam is really awesome! and thanks for the ref. links as well.