# Passing name-value pair from a map as query parameters in JAX-RS client

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

I am trying to access one existing REST service from my client side using JAX-RS client as below-

```
public interface ServerApi {
      @POST
      @Path("/server/{type}/add")
      void addServer(@PathParam("type") String type);
}
```

Here I want to pass a map as method parameter and JAX-RS client will convert that to query parameters.

For example, if I pass a map (`[name=test, vendor=top1]`) as parameter (i,e, `serverApi.addServer("linux", map);`),  JAX-RS client will transform it to `/server/linux/add?name=test&vendor=top1`

**I tried to write the client interface method as below -**

```
public interface ServerApi {
          @POST
          @Path("/server/{type}/add")
          void addServer(@PathParam("type") String type, @PathParam("map") Map<String, String> aMap);
    }
```

But it will not work as client will assign the entire map to map key and pass that query parameter and I am not expecting that.

Can anyone help me to achieve this using JAX-RS client

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722506/how-do-you-map-multiple-query-parameters-to-the-fields-of-a-bean-on-jersey-get-r

Comment: @user7294900 - No, it is not the same thing that I am looking for