# How to use the query parameters in Java Jersey Application?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am following a tutorial and also used the Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718575/how-can-i-grab-all-query-parameters-in-jersey-jaxrs?noredirect=1&lq=1).
Here is my Java class:

```
package com.crunchify.tutorial;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

@Path("api")
public class CrunchifyAPI {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String get(
            @DefaultValue("111") @QueryParam("user") int user,
            @Context UriInfo uriInfo
            ) {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
        String nameParam = queryParams.getFirst("user");
        System.out.println("Data Received: " + uriInfo.getRequestUri().getQuery()
                + " | " + nameParam);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("auth", true);
        String ret = JSONObject.toJSONString(obj);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Following is what I am GET'ing from postman:

```
GET>> localhost/api/get?user=123
```

*Response* is:

```
{"auth":true}
```

Server console:

```
Starting Crunchify's Embedded Jersey HTTPServer...

Started Crunchify's Embedded Jersey HTTPServer Successfully !!!
Data Received: ?user=123 | null
User Authenticated: true
```

I have tried with passing String, Integer etc but nothing works. The uri Info is getting printed correctly and the response back is also fine. The issue is that I am not getting the parameter to be read in Java Code. I will need to pass many other parameters once I am able to get this going. Please suggest. Thanks!!

Comment: I am hoping that it will print following in the server console:
`Data Received: ?user=123 | 123`
Similarly, later on I would like to pass String and (if possible, may be JSON).

Answer (score 6):

I think you're trying too hard. As far as I can tell, doing the following should get you what you want if you call localhost/api/get?user=123:

```
package com.crunchify.tutorial;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

@Path("api")
public class CrunchifyAPI {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String get(
            @DefaultValue("111") @QueryParam("user") Integer user,
            @Context UriInfo uriInfo
            ) {
        System.out.println("Data Received: " + uriInfo.getRequestUri().getQuery()
                + " | " + name);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("auth", true);
        String ret = JSONObject.toJSONString(obj);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

All that extra stuff with the query string isn't needed if all you need is the information passed in the user parameter.

Answer (score 1):

@QueryParam("user") int user

the value of that user int should be 123

See https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/

Comment: Yes. I am expecting the following lines to display 123 instead of null:

`String nameParam = queryParams.getFirst("user");
 System.out.println("Data Received: " + uriInfo.getRequestUri().getQuery() + " | " + nameParam);`
I have even tried changing int to String and Integer. Nothing works!

Comment: try System.out.println(user);

Comment: I tried that and it prints 111 instead of null i.e. the default value.
`String nameParam = queryParams.getFirst("user");
System.out.println("Data Received: " + uriInfo.getRequestUri().getQuery() + " | " + nameParam);
System.out.println(user);`

Result:
`Data Received: ?user=aaaaa | null
111`   --> should be **123**

Comment: not sure if the issue is mixing two paradims, either use QueryParam or UriInfo, clean up your code, if needed, create two test methods See https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you're having a problem with Java Types.

If your user is an `Integer` you should pass it to `String` first if you want to work with a `String` (`Integer.toString()` or `String.valueof()`).

But the way you're passing the parameter is bothering me, I'm not sure if you can pass integers by text plain medi types.